# Get android:versionName with shell command

Tags: android, shell, command-line

I want to get the versionName from the AndroidManist.xml file with a shell command.
I've been trying to use grep and with:

```
 grep versionName ./AndroidManifest.xml
```

I'm getting this line:

```
android:versionName="1.0">
```

Is it possible to narrow it down to **1.0** somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
perl -e 'while($line=<>) { if ($line=~ /versionName\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/) { print "$1\n";}}' <AndroidManifest.xml
```

You may want to put this into a file :

Ex: VersionNum.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

#get the filename from command line
$file = shift or die;

#open the file and read it into $lines var
open(IN,$file) or die;
$lines=join("",<IN>); 
close(IN);

#search the $line var for match and print it
if ($lines =~ m/android:versionName\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/mgs)  {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Then simply `chmod 755 VersionNumber.pl` and use it with `VersionNumber.pl AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version could be derived from your original suggestion:

```
grep versionCode AndroidManifest.xml | sed -e 's/.*versionName\s*=\s*\"\([0-9.]*\)\".*/\1/g'
```

Comment: grep versionCode AndroidManifest.xml | cut -d\" -f2

Comment: One thing to think about is when you have versionCode="" and versionName="" both on the same line. either one preceded by the other.